# How to format colorbar label in Bokeh

Tags: bokeh, holoviews

I have generated a `holoviews` \ `Bokeh` [heatmap graph](http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/us_unemployment.html#bokeh-gallery-us-unemployment) similar to the example.
I added a colorbar in the `plot_opts` with `colorbar=True`, but the labels of the colorbar comes out as a scientific number.
How do I control the format of the label?
I tried implementing the following code without success:

```
cbf = PrintfTickFormatter(format='0,0')
color_bar = ColorBar(formatter=cbf)
```

and then add it to the `plot_opts` but it did not change anything.

I looked at this [user guide documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/dev/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#color-bars) and this [model documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/annotations.html#ColorBar)  but did not manage to figure out how to implement the property.

**UPDATE**
Here is the full code Which still doesn't work.

```
dfqudf.head()
```

|**INDEX**|**dow**|**hour**|**QUERYTYPE**|
|-------|-------|--------|-------------|
|72|    Sunday| 0   |205104|
|24|    Monday| 0   |210293|
|120|   Tuesday|    0   |206381|
|144|   Wednesday|  0   |212874|
|96|    Thursday|   0   |216195|

```
hv.extension('bokeh')
colors = ["#75968f", "#a5bab7", "#c9d9d3", "#e2e2e2", "#dfccce", "#ddb7b1", "#cc7878", "#933b41", "#550b1d"]
heatmap = hv.HeatMap(data=dfqudf[['hour','dow','QUERYTYPE']]
                     , label="Query Hour by Weekday")

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Num of Queries', '@QUERYTYPE{0,0}')])

formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format='0,0')  #PrintfTickFormatter(format='%.1f') doesn't work either
color_bar = {'formatter': formatter}
plot_opts = dict(width=900, height=300, xrotation=45, xaxis='top', labelled=[]
                 , tools=[hover], toolbar='below'
                 , colorbar=True, colorbar_opts= color_bar
                )
style = dict(cmap=ListedColormap(colors))

heatmap(plot=plot_opts, style=style)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `hv.help(element)` you can find out what options you can customize an Element with. Elements that support colormapping (including HeatMap) accept a `colorbar_opts` plot option which are passed through to the ColorBar constructor. Here's a very simple example:

```
from bokeh.models import PrintfTickFormatter
formatter = PrintfTickFormatter(format='%.1f')
plot_opts = dict(colorbar=True, colorbar_opts={'formatter': formatter})
hv.HeatMap([(0,0,0), (1,1,1)]).opts(plot=plot_opts)
```

Comment: Thx for the direction

Comment: I tried using the `PrintfTickFormatter` and the `NumeralTickFormatter` but in both cases the format of the number did not change. Any ideas?

Comment: Mind posting exactly what you've tried because the example above works fine for me.